# Android: Adding Layouts Dynamically By Inflating XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to have a function where a layout is added to my view when a button is pressed. The ID's of 2 `EditText`s in the layout are added to a `List<EditText>`, so I can access them no matter how many instances of the XML layout are added. However, I'm having troubles getting this to work.

Main function setting up the view:

```
    ViewGroup view = null;
    TextView addressView;
    Button submit;
    ImageView addHeader;

    private int id = 0;
    private List<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);

        view = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.getLayout);


        addressView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.getAddress);
        submit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.getSubmit);
        addHeader = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.getHeaderAdd);

        addHeader.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addHeaderBox();
            }           
        });
```

My function adding the layout:

```
private void addHeaderBox() {    
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_param, view, false);

    EditText nameBox = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.getValue);
    EditText valueBox = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.getName);

    nameBox.setId(id++);
    valueBox.setId(id++);

    editTexts.add(nameBox);
    editTexts.add(valueBox);
}
```

`getValue` and `getName` are the ID's of the two `EditText`s in my layout (not the main `getLayout`).

```
07-19 10:25:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(32034): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 10:25:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(32034):    at myapp.httprequest.free.GETActivity.addHeaderBox(GETActivity.java:96)
07-19 10:25:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(32034):    at myapp.httprequest.free.GETActivity.access$0(GETActivity.java:88)
07-19 10:25:13.088: E/AndroidRuntime(32034):    at myapp.httprequest.free.GETActivity$1.onClick(GETActivity.java:65)
```

Line 96 is `nameBox.setId(id++)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
.......
View someView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_param, view, false);

EditText nameBox = (EditText) someView.findViewById(R.id.getValue);
EditText valueBox = (EditText) someView.findViewById(R.id.getName);
........
```

Answer (score 1):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_param, view, false);
```

Inflater inflates but result of inflating is not assigned to any view object.

Comment: It's initialized right when I declared it: `private List<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();`