# Android multiple view.xml files and how to use them

Tags: android, android-layout

I am very new to android and I am looking for a best practice here. I have a simple 2 view layout. At the top is a text area where I can enter a product number, and then right below it, display the data for that product. (I am new to all this so the product id is hard coded right now)  Here is my main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_loading"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/product_data_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the lookup uses the internet so it is done using a AsyncTask.

I have another layout file (product_data.xml) that lays out all the info. Now I could have one big activity_main.xml that has both, but down the line, there will be different product_data.xml files for different types of products, so I want to do this dynamically

(My only UI experience is HTML so I am looking at this like filling a DIV tag with my jQuery results.  I want to fill @+id/product_data_view with my product_data.xml layout)

My question is - It this the correct thinking?  Am I on the right path, or am I miss understanding a basic droid concept?

After some research, I think I need to use an Intent that starts an Activity that loads my product_data.xml -- but how then do I attach that view to the @+id/product_data_view of the main view? is View what I want there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inflate the product_data.xml layout dynamically based on the product and then populate the data for the layout. Check this question on how to inflate layout dynamically, [Android: Adding Layouts Dynamically By Inflating XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563094/android-adding-layouts-dynamically-by-inflating-xml)

Hope it helps.

Comment: That did it thanks.  But I could not use a View, I had to use a ViewGroup (which, in the xml, will not work as it is abstract) So I used a FrameLayout. But my product_data.xml layout begins with a RelativeLayout.  In my mind, once product_data is inflated, I would have a RelativeLayout directly inside a FrameLayout.  Is this correct thinking?  Is this correct best practice? and is there a concrete subclass of ViewGroup that does nothing, and is simply a place holder for this type of thing?

Comment: That would be fine IMHO. Make the background of FrameLayout to null as it is just a placeholder for relative layout. So that you can avoid some overdraw. If you are not familiar with overdraw then just google about how to avoid overdraw and  you will get the help.  This is to improve the performance by avoiding overdraw when you have multiple views in a layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your target is creating a custom view of product data. That can be a customized list view, then you can fill your product data dynamically through an Adapter class.

The first, you should research about how to create a customized view class. Here can be a reference [[Android custom views article]](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html).

The second, you will add your customized view into activity main like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.your.CustomView" >


android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_loading"/>

<com.your.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/product_data_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Happy coding!